# Python and tkinter confusion

Tags: python, tkinter

I am completely new to Python. The basics are pretty clear at the moment. I am trying to build a simple GUI for the first time and ran into tkinter. I copied a bit of code and ran it. It works.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = TK()
root.title("test")
```

Then I wanted to alter and add code, created a new file and started typing:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter ttk
root = TK()
root.title("smartDisplay")
```

And guess what... It doesn't work. It says "*name 'TK' is not defined*". It is the same Mac the same IDE, the same folder of the two files. So what is going on here? What am I missing?

I am using python 3.8.2 on a Mac with 10.15.7

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is Tk(), not TK()

Comment: Also in your second line it is from tkinter import ttk.

Comment: Now I am feeling so dumb... That was the mistake. Thanks! I guess I need to change the font. You can hardly see the difference.

Comment: No problem. Everybody makes mistakes. Please close the question..

Answer (score 0):

Python is case sensitive and needs `root = Tk()`. Also I didn't see a `root.mainloop()` at the end of your code. That is also needed to run the Tkinter window.

Comment: Unless you run it from IDLE or something similar